# Is this casting, what kind of and operator is this

Tags: c, struct

```
data_ptr = (struct db_table_s *) &(db_table[0]);
```

I have a line of code like this, in C, What does this code do? Is it type casting or a bitwise operator?

```
struct db_table_s
{
    unsigned short int      d_event_code;
    int             (*db_read__image)(),
                    (*db_write_image)();
};

const struct db_table_s                         db_table[] =
{
    {   DB_seq1,                    
        _read_func,     
        _write_func,            
    },
    {   DB_seq2 ,                   
        _read_func1 ,   
        _write_func2,                                   
    }
};
```

Comment: Please show the actual definitions of `data_ptr`, `db_table` and `struct db` instead of describing them.

Comment: `db_table` must be a pointer, not a struct. You can read about [address-of operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Address_of).

Comment: @KamilCuk Or an array; arrays are not pointers even though they decay to pointers.

Comment: Is cast necessary ? `&(db_table[0])` is a `struct db_table_s *`.

Comment: the cast is here to remove the "const"

Comment: This is an old style cast, this is replaced in modern C++ compilers with a static_cast.  Assuming that ' data_ptr' is declared as a pointer to an instance of struct db_stable_s, all this line does is extract a single element from the array 'db_table' and assign its address to 'data_ptr'.

Comment: @SPlatten - The question is C, not C++.

Comment: @SPlatten dude...

Comment: @KamilCuk Why would db_table need to be a pointer? If it is a plain struct, `&db_table` should work, if it is an array, `db_table` should work as well. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @GermanNerd `db_table[0]` -> The subscript operator needs a pointer. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access) - `pointer-expression - an expression of type pointer to complete object` , from [C11 6.5.2.1p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1) `One of the expressions shall have type ''pointer to complete object type''` (the other expression is integer 0). My comment was to the post before an edit.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk I am aware of the subscript operator. I still do not understand your comment; maybe you could provide the original code before the edit? I can't see anything relevant to your comment in the edit history. (Might be blind.)

Comment: @GermanNerd OP had originally written `db_table is a const struct list` in revision 1. The code `(db_table[0])` is still there.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk Ah, thanks. Yes, that original line does not even make sense.

Comment: Please show the actual definitions of `data_ptr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast is present just to transform a *const address* to a *non const address*.

`db_table` is a vector of `const struct db_table_s`, then `db_table[0]` is a `const struct db_table_s`, then `&(db_table[0])` is a `const struct db_table_s *`

Probably the code wants (badly) to memorize that pointer while we have `struct db_table_s * data_ptr;` so it is needed to cast to avoid a warning.

The cast is useless in case of `const struct db_table_s * data_ptr;`

P.S. in your code there are missing ',' and ';' :-(

Comment: those arrows means something like foo =>val  = foo*.val ? or logical operators?

Comment: @MericOzcan yes, I supposed that clear but visibly no, so I replaced _=>_ by _then_

Answer (score 3):

Your code will assign the address of first element in `db_table` array (which is the same as the address of the array), cast as `struct db_table_s *` pointer type, to `data_ptr`.